# on_stop event not getting called in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I need to use on_stop event in Kivy but it seems not to be working . please see below code

Any Advice : I am using kivy 1.8

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sound = SoundLoader.load("some_sound.ogg")
        sound.on_stop = sound.play
        sound.play()



        return Widget()

if __name__ in ('__android__', '__main__'):
    MyApp().run()
```

I even tried using state to run the sound in loop however its very weird that even when the song is stopped it still prints its state as play . Can someone advice what is wrong in this ?

Below Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.clock import Clock


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load("playScreen.wav")
        self.sound.on_stop = self.update
        self.sound.play()

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1.0/1)
        return Widget()

    def update(self,dt):
        print "state is ",self.sound.state
        if self.sound.state == 'stop':
            self.sound.play()

if __name__ in ('__android__', '__main__'):
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: FYI: You should use `bind` for events - by setting the `on_stop` attribute you are overwriting the default handler for the event. So that should be written as `self.sound.bind(on_stop=lambda *_: sound.play())`. Also note the `lambda` -- this is necessary to squelch the arguments for the event. There aren't any arguments for this event, so in this case the `lambda` doesn't matter, but it's a good standard practice (unless you've written a handler that takes the correct arguments).

Comment: I did try bind , it also didnt work .

Comment: In this case it won't work either way, because of the bug. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `audio_gstplayer.py` - when EOS is reached, the `GstPlayer` is stopped, but the `Sound.state` is not updated, nor is the `on_stop` event fired.

If you just want the sound to continually loop, however, you can set the `loop` property.

```
sound = SoundLoader.load('some_sound.ogg')
sound.loop = True
sound.play()
```

EDIT: Submitted pull request https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/2131